# Convert and format a list to string in erlang

Tags: list, erlang

I have a list in erlang which I need to convert to a querystring parameter and send over http. The sending over http is no problem, however the querystring parameter is not formatted in the way I want. I tried two things:

**Snippet 1**

```
error_logger:info_msg("~p", [Mylist]),  %% ==> prints [<<"foo">>,<<"bar">>] 
Response = httpc:request("http://someserver/someaction?mylist=" ++ [Mylist]). 
%% ==> Server receives Mylist param as: 'foobar' but I want it to be 'foo/bar'
```

**Snippet 2**

```
error_logger:info_msg("~p", [Mylist]),  %% ==> prints [<<"foo">>,<<"bar">>] 
IOList = io_lib:format("~p", [Mylist]),
FlatList = lists:flatten([IOList]),
Response = httpc:request("http://someserver/someaction?mylist=" ++ [FlatList]).
%% ==> Server receives Mylist param as: '[<<"foo">>,<<"bar">>]' but I want it to be 'foo/bar'
```

Can someone help me with converting and formatting the list in a way that I can receive all items in the list seperated with a '/' character

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a `/` character to appear between the list elements in the URL, you have to put it there. One way to do that is with [`lists:join/2`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#join-2):

```
Response = httpc:request("http://someserver/someaction?mylist=" ++ lists:join("/", Mylist)).
```

This results in an iolist consisting of strings and binaries being passed as the URL argument to `httpc:request/1`, which worked for me when I tried it, but is strictly not correct since the [`httpc` documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/man/httpc.html) says the URL type is a string. To achieve that, you can convert the binaries in `Mylist` first and flatten the joined result to get a string:

```
Value = lists:flatten(lists:join("/", [binary_to_list(B) || B <- Mylist])),
Response = httpc:request("http://someserver/someaction?mylist=" ++ Value).
```

Edit: note that `lists:join/2` is available only in Erlang/OTP 19.0 or newer; for older releases, you can use [`string:join/2`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/string.html#join-2) instead, but note that the arguments are reversed, i.e. the `"/"` separator must be the second argument, not the first.

Comment: Note that `lists:join/2` was only added in the recent 19.x. Can use `string:join/2` in this case for earlier releases.